# How to put buttons at the bottom of the label?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I follow [Developing iOS 8 Apps with Swift](https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/developing-ios-8-apps-swift/id961180099) course. The calculator is being developed there. As the first step, I add label (display) with the following constraints -

- right - trailing space to Superview
- left - leading space to Superview
- top - top space to Top Layout Guide.Bottom with value 8

Then I should add the button (digit 7 in my case) and put it in the left top corner, but below the label. But it doesn't work - when I take and move the button (or all buttons as shown on the screenshot below), then the left blue line indicating left constraint appears, but there is no line indicating bottom constraint of the label.

What is wrong there? How to place buttons exactly below the label?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

First of all in your case you should embed all the buttons in a single view and then add constrains in that view relative to superview (be aware that now buttons should have constrains relative to newly created view). To do that select all the buttons go to Editor->Embed In->View. The created view cant have top-left and below display constrains in same time because top and below are conflicted constrains. So next add the left constrain for the view and vertical space between display and view with following rule : Display.Bottom equal View.Top with a constant of your value. Finally your 7 button should be placed top left of its superivew

Comment: Thanks, zelib. Actually, I've found my mistake - I've used wrong options when applied Pin functionality - used fixed Width and Height instead of Equal Widths and Equal Heights. So, it is not really required to combine all buttons into a single view.